# Fast NumPy expression for partial reconstruction of image from SVD

Tags: python, numpy

I want to take the SVD of an image (treating each of the four RGBa channels separately), and then reconstruct the image using only the first `N` vectors. I have the code below, which works as expected, but I would ideally like to write the reconstruction without using `np.stack`. I'd rather like to use some clever broadcasting trick to achieve the same result.

```
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# Load image (python logo from python.org)
img = mpimg.imread('https://www.python.org/static/img/python-logo@2x.png')
# img has shape (164, 580, 4)

# Take SVD, using transpose to get the 4 as
# the first dimension, which makes np.linalg.svd
# treat it as 4 separate 580 x 164 matrices
U, S, V = np.linalg.svd(img.T)
# U has shape (4, 580, 580)
# S has shape (4, 164)
# V has shape (4, 164, 164)

# Reconstruct image with the first N vectors,
# using np.stack(..., axis = -1) to get the 4
# as the last dimension, as in the original image
N = 3
img_reconstructed = np.stack((
    np.dot(U[0,:,:N], S[0,:N,None]*V[0,:N,:]).T, # Red channel
    np.dot(U[1,:,:N], S[1,:N,None]*V[1,:N,:]).T, # Green channel
    np.dot(U[2,:,:N], S[2,:N,None]*V[2,:N,:]).T, # Blue channel
    np.dot(U[3,:,:N], S[3,:N,None]*V[3,:N,:]).T, # alpha channel
), axis = -1)
# img_reconstructed has shape (164, 580, 4), 
# just like the original image

plt.imshow(img_reconstructed)
```

I thought maybe I could achieve the same with `np.tensordot`, but I couldn't get it to work. I tried

```
img_reconstructed = np.tensordot(U[:,:,:n], S[:,:n,None]*V[:,:n,:], axes = ((2), (1))).T
```

but it comes out with shape `(164, 4, 580, 4)`, instead of `(164, 580, 4)` as I had hoped.

I managed to get a working solution with `np.einsum`:

```
img_reconstructed = np.einsum('...ij,...jk->ki...', U[:,:,:n], S[:,:n,None]*V[:,:n,:])
```

but when I time it, I find that it's about 25 times slower than the solution above with `np.stack`.

Comment: `matmul/@` is better for batches of `dot`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can broadcast using `@` instead of `np.dot`.

```
U, S, V = np.linalg.svd(img.T)
N = 3
img_reconstructed = (U[:,:,:N] @ (S[:,:N,None]*V[:,:N,:])).T
```

Comment: When I time this, I find it to be about five or six times faster than my first attempt with `np.stack`, so this is exactly the kind of think I was looking for. Thanks a lot!